# Group chat in a Lan application

Tags: java, chat, server

I have developed a LAN chat application in java.I am using client server model and I am able to send messages to particular user as well as to all the users logged in. Now my problem is I want to create a group chat then how do I save the group chat when clients logout and login again. I mean members that are added to the group.

It is a LAN application.Once a group chat is created and members added then it should remain for the next time the clients login.Can somebody please guide me regarding the same please?

Comment: I guess you'll have to keep such info in a database. Then if a user logs in, you'll have to add his connection to the respective chats. If you want the users to see what has been chatted while they were offline, you'll have to keep the chatprotocols, also and keep track of which user has received which messages.

Comment: @Fildor-chatprotocols like?.Can you please elaborate.

Comment: chatprotocol like Data: Chat, Date/Time, User, Messagetext ...

Comment: @Fildor-Can i use XMPP?

Comment: Ah. I was not talking about that kind of chatprotcol. I meant just the plain chat data. You need to keep it so all groupchatters have the same data as soon as they log in again.

Comment: @Fildor-Ok thanks i got that.But i also want to ask you can we develop a LAN Chat application using XMPP.

Comment: Of course you can. There are plenty of docu on XMPP.

Comment: @Fildor-I did research alot however i did not find any doc which says that i can develop a LAN chat application using XMPP.Can you please suggest any docs.

Comment: Here you go: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6120